# R rm() function on processed code

Tags: r

Whats with rm()? I can remove an object using a string, but it seems that a processing resulting in a string does not work:

```
obj <- "my.obj"
o.str <- "obj.test"
class(sub("[.]test","",o.str)) # "character"
class("obj") # "character"
identical(sub("[.]test","",o.str),"obj") # "TRUE"
rm("obj") # works
obj <- "my.obj"
rm(sub("[.]test","",o.str))
# error:
# Error in rm(sub("[.]test", "", o.str)) : 
#   ... must contain names or character strings
```

why?

Comment: Nice find. This is due to `match.call` behaviour. Try `testfunc <- function(...){
  match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$...
} ; testfunc("obj") ; testfunc(sub("[.]test","",o.str))` and compare results (The first is a string, while the second is unevaluated expression). You can also mimic the mechanism that triggering this behaviour using `testfunc <- function(...){
  dots <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$...
  sapply(dots, function(x) is.character(x))
} ; testfunc("obj") ; testfunc(sub("[.]test","",o.str))`. Though I'm not sure why this mechanism was created in `rm` in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what's happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better way to remove values with a given character string is via the `list=` argument

```
rm(list=sub("[.]test","",o.str))
```

The way the "..." is documented is that it expects the objects as either quoted or unquoted names. It doesn't expect a function that will return names. That's what `list=` is for.

Comment: Thanks. Seems this is the only way to delete objects in a setting where object names are not known in advance.